# What are the following documents about aircraft maintenance?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

1. What is a service bulletin? How does it originate?
2. What is a rapid revision in aircraft maintenance?
3. What is a non-conformation report?

What is the difference between these 3 documents?

Answer (score 5):

A service bulletin is a document that the manufacturer of an aircraft issues directly to operators of related aircraft. It mandates some maintenance / replacement / check activities.

A rapid revision is a change to the maintenance documents, that is not released officially according to normal procedures, yet.

A non conformation report is any discrepancy found in the aircraft / system such that the related system does not look / operate / behave / function as expected. This document is mostly a form that the ground crew / technicians / pilots generate.

Disclaimer: these are general information and details would change depending on whether the aircraft is a civil or military one, and the certification type. This answer is written in the perspective of military aircraft, for general knowledge.

Comment: How does these change for civil aircraft?

Comment: For civil aircraft, service bulletins are mainly related to product changes that are not safety related (except for Mandatory Service Bulletins). They are changes to the systems that improve functionality, or replace parts that are obsolete, etc.

Comment: You can get details of procedures for a particular certification authority, such as FAA, EASA, from their web sites.

Comment: I will check the sites. thank you